# Is it possible to use Intent.ACTION_PICK to access a res/raw file for a picture?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to use (Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
or something similar to access a res/raw file of pictures? If so what changes would need to be made to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a custom database instead of relying on the MediaStore.

Answer (score 0):

Its not much clear what you are asking but if you want to use pictures from res then first put these picture in res/drawable, now we can use this picture in many way as

for in background property(in layout)

**android:background="@drawable/mypic"**

in image view(in layout)

```
<ImageView>
...
android:src="@drawable/mypic"
</ImageView>
```

in image view(in activity code)

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mypic));
```

Comment: Sorry to be unclear, what I really meant to ask was if it was possible to use the MediaStore/built in gallery viewer to pick a picture from a  set of pictures supplied in the res/raw (or even asset) folder of my app and only from that folder specifically and not from the rest of the images/pictures stored in the phone. Or do I have to build a database etc. Cant quite find an example thats using the MediaStore to access only those folders and excludes everything else.